# Laravel eloquent - undefined variable

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Im have been learning laravel, and now im using for the first time eloquent. But im getting an error. it doesnt recognize the variable that represents the query. I have searched for solutions in the net, but cant get any to solve the problem. Im using laravel version 5.4. Can anyone help?

the error: "Undefined variable: articles" (on the teste7.blade)

the code:

web

```
Route::get('teste7', 'CentralController@teste7');
Route::get('/article/{article}', ['as' => 'article', 'uses' => 'CentralController@article']);
```

Controller

```
    use App\article;

    function teste7(){
    $articles=article::pagination(4);
    return view('teste7');
}
function article($article){
    return view($article);
}
```

teste7

```
{{ $articles->total() }} articles
<b>In this page ({{ $articles->count() }} articles )</b>
<ul>
@foreach ($articles as $article)
<li> <a href="{{route('article', ['artigo' => $article->Name])}}">{{ 
$article->Name }}</a></li>
@endforeach
</ul>
{{ $articles->links() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the data into the view using the second parameter. You can find more information in the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#creating-views).

```
function teste7() {
    $articles = article::pagination(4);
    return view('teste7', ['articles' => $articles]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CentralController extends Controller
{
   public function teste7()
   {
       $articles = article::pagination(4);

       // returns view 'teste7.blade.php' and passes the $articles variable along
       return view('teste7', compact('articles'));
   }
}
```

In your `article()` function, you're not correctly returning a view. In your `teste7()` function, you're returning a view ('teste7.blade.php'), but not passing any variables to the view.

It is very important that you pass variables from the controller to the view. Otherwise they will **not** be accessible from within the view.

Comment: Ok. Now it says "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pagination()". What does this mean? is pagination()  only applicable to the "user" model?